# Programmatically detect the name, location and start time of a social event on any html page

Tags: architecture, nlp, machine-learning

I would love to see an app/browser extension that automatically detects meatspace events on a page by looking for words like location, date, time, etc... and then offers to add these to a calendar

If there is a large enough sample of these occurrences is there anyway to train an app to detect it? Are there any machine learning technique that could help with this?

Comment: You'll need to break the problem down further to receive any valuable feedback.  eg, How do I programmatically recognize location, date, and time values on an HTML page?  How do I interface with a user's calendar application?

Comment: I don't think the issue is the size of the sample - the problem is how to bring those from "meat-space" into virtual space.  When you say "events on a page" what exactly do you mean? A web page?

Comment: @tQuarella, you are right. I will use your input to make that question more specific.
@When I am on the web page for a public lecture, seminar, workshop, course, etc... I would like to programatically detect name, location and starting time for that event.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write grammar for detection things like date/time/location. You can check example here http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with that but it seem promising.